# Can Not Delete What Isn't There

Tags: diskpart

Over the last week or so I have been trying out external USB blu-ray drives from different manufacturers.  After a time they stopped working.  None of them worked.
Uninstall. Install. Load drivers...nothing.
Then I noticed a drive listed under portable devices (device manager) that really didn't exist.  I eventually deleted it with diskpart; list volume; select volume;delete.
That worked ONCE.
The phantom has returned and no matter WHAT I do, it reappears at each re-boot.
I Can Not Delete What Isn't There.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. What does it have to do with audio? Please specify your operating system and [edit] the post.

Comment: What exactly is a portable blue-ray disk?

Comment: The audio tag was incorrect, it has been edited. I have edited the Bluray disk reference.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do with `diskpart`. Device Manager lists devices and you can't delete a device with `diskpart`, only a partition in it if it's recognized as a writable storage.

Comment: Maybe @kkorotev is talking about an External Universal Serial Bus Blu-Ray _ReWritable_ Drive, guys. We were also wanting once to perform the achievement of buying such an intricate Unit. We are glad that we did not did it in the long run. They see something in the _Device Manager_. They have **_eventually_** deleted some kind of Software Partition using the `diskpart` Software Utility. Maybe it is a Software Partition that is used by the ReWriting Mechanism of that Portable Electronic Device. If it is so, then it is absolutely normal for it to reappear after each boot.

Comment: As my phantom device is showing up as a volume in diskpart (not as a disk); I have selected the phantom volume and tried Delete Volume...all as I said in my original post.  I worked once.  Through help from members of other forums, we have manged to get the device unluisted in device manager, but it still returns to MYPC as a drive/CD  on every re-boot.  Disabling the Portable Devive enumerator from SERVICES.MSI has no effect.

Comment: DOBRESCU, Could you explain more of what you mean by this: Maybe it is a Software Partition that is used by the ReWriting Mechanism of that Portable Electronic Device. If it is so, then it is absolutely normal for it to reappear after each boot.

Comment: External and temporary rewritable mobile electronic devices _should_ have this behavior, @kkorotev. Each of their connections to the main machine _should_ produce a temporary rewritable software primary partition. We simply do not understand why you thought that deleting this partition would make the device work.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it. It's hardware thing.
Unplug USB connection to external player.
Disable phantom drive in device manager.
Disable portable enumerator service.
DISABLE GENERIC USB STORAGE DEVICE in device manager.
Reboot.
All gone. Nothing there.
Re-connect external player...it finds itself but phantom drive does not.

I'll run like this for a while then see if I can reverse ANY of the disabled things.

Like all things Win10...bang it around a few times and if you're right it will correct itself.

Kevin

Comment: Thanks for your discovery.  When you make questions in the future, please make the title more descriptive.  Screenshots can also help, so that future readers can benefit from your findings.